# Method returns an array, and the select query doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method in my model that returns an array:

```
     public function status($s_type)
        {
            if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
                return false;
            }

            $o_status = Status::where('name', strval($s_type))->first();
            $o_response = $this->statuses()
                ->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
                ->select('values', 'created_at')
                ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                ->first();

            if($o_response === null){
                return false;
            }

            return [
                'value' => $o_response->values,
                'timestamp' => $o_response->created_at
            ];
        }

I want to get the timestamp. So, I called this method in a controller. it uses an  

    public function status(){

        $client = new Client();
        $notification=Notification::where('active',1)->get();
        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

        foreach ($notification as $note) {

            $status_health = $note->status('health');
            $status_health['timestamp'];


            print_r($status_health);
            echo '<br>';
/*
            ;
            }*/
        }

    }
```

I want to print only the time stamp? now it is printing the whole object.
the Print_r is printing the whole object instead of timestamp only. I am really bad with associative array.

Comment: where are you calling that first method? I only see calls to models not controller methods.

Comment: If you want to receive good answers, you need to be more precise about the problems you're dealing with. BTW, you don't call a controller method from other controllers. If you feel the urge to do so, it's a smell in your code. If two controllers need to do something in common, that common task needs to be extracted into another non-controller class. Remember, controllers are just transport layers.

Comment: @ SepehrLajevardi: you are right. 'haste makes west'. my model returns an array from the database, value and timestamp. i want to iterate through the timestamp column in the database and extract all the timestamps. that is why in my controller, i itrated through all the notification using the foreach loop in my controller, and then i wrote this query to just collect only the time stamp: ::: $note->status('health')
            ->select('created_at')
            ->latest()
            ->first()

Comment: it is complaining saying that i can't call the select function in array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that this is all the code we need to comprehend the problem? I'm asking here, because the error message says that you are calling `get()` on an array, yet the only two uses of `get()` in the code you provided are

```
$notification = Notification::where('active',1)->get();
```

(Called on query builder -> valid)

and

```
$response = $client->get($note->website_url);
```

I couldn't find a `get()` method in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, but maybe you wrote one or I'm missing something. In either case, `$client` is not an array, so that line can not be responsible for the error. So, I think the error is in some part of your code that you didn't show us yet.

There's one other thing that caught my eye: In your `status($s_type)` method, right at the beginning, you're saying

```
if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
    return false;
}
```

then you call that method later with

```
$check_frequency = $note->status('timestamp');
```

so this will always be `false`.

Comment: Now i changed my approach into associative array, where I am not good with associative array. i will l edit what I am doing now.